# After upgrade to php 7 plugin/them updates broke

Tags: plugins, php, updates, ssh

I upgraded my Ubuntu server to php 7 and setup ssh2. Afterwards, my WordPress plugins/themes will not update.  I am receiving the Unable to locate WordPress Content directory (wp-content). This feature worked fine prior using php 5. My permissions were not changed and remain 755 (folders) 644 (files).

I am using the same ssh user as before, which is my primary user on the server.  I unzipped the php7.zip file to create the pecl-networking-ssh2-php7 directory in my user's home directory.  I made the extension and set it in the php.ini file.

Any ideas on what is hanging the plugin updater?

Comment: Do you have all errors and warnings reporting turned on in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing php-ssh2, which removes libssh2-php on the install.

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-ssh2
```

I also had to change permissions on the wp-content folder to 775, but it worked leaving the wp-content/plugins at 755.

```
$ chmod 775 wp-content
```